# How to partition to multiple .csv from df based on whitespace row?

Tags: r, csv, export

I'm working with a database that has a timestamp, 3 numeric vectors, and a character vector.

Basically, each "set" of data is delineated by a new row. I need each series of rows to save as .csv when the row reads that each column is empty (x = \t\r\n). There's about 370 in my dataset.

For example,

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(x1 = 1:4,
                   x2 = 4:1,
                   x3 = 3,
                   x4 = c("text", "no text", "example", "hello"))

new_row <- c("\t\r\n", "\t\r\n", "\t\r\n", "\t\r\n")

data1 <- rbind(data, new_row)

data2 <- data.frame(x1 = 1:4,
                    x2 = 4:1,
                    x3 = 4,
                    x4 = c("text", "no text", "example", "hello"))

data2 <- rbind(data2, new_row)


data3 <- rbind(data1, data2)

view(data3)
```

This is what my data set looks like (without the timestamp). I need every set of consecutive rows after a row full or \t\r\n to be exported as an individual .csv.

I'm doing text analysis. Each group of rows, with highly variable group size, represents a thread on different subject. I need to analyze these individual threads.

What is the best way to go about doing this? I haven't had this problem before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
ind <- grepl("\t", data3$x4)
ind <- replace(cumsum(ind), ind, -1)
ind
#  [1]  0  0  0  0 -1  1  1  1  1 -1

data4 <- split(data3, ind)
data4
# $`-1`
#       x1    x2    x3    x4
# 5  \t\r\n \t\r\n \t\r\n \t\r\n
# 10 \t\r\n \t\r\n \t\r\n \t\r\n
# $`0`
#   x1 x2 x3      x4
# 1  1  4  3    text
# 2  2  3  3 no text
# 3  3  2  3 example
# 4  4  1  3   hello
# $`1`
#   x1 x2 x3      x4
# 6  1  4  4    text
# 7  2  3  4 no text
# 8  3  2  4 example
# 9  4  1  4   hello
```

The use of `-1` was solely to keep the `"\t\r\n"` rows from being included in each of their respective groups, and we know that `cumsum(ind)` should start at `0`. You can obviously drop the first frame :-)

From here, you can export with

```r
data4 <- data4[-1]
ign <- Map(write.csv, data4, sprintf("file_%03d.csv", seq_along(data4)))
```